# If given Model.find(:all), how to get the name of the Model/Class from the given result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
m = Model.find(1);
```

m.class_name would give you "Model"

If we have:

```
m = Model.find(:all);
```

How do we get the name of the model from m alone?

Answer (score 3):

Get the class of the first entry in the returned array

```
m.first.class
```

Comment: This won't work quite correctly if you've got inheritence. Given, say, `Media < ActiveRecord::Base`, `Record < Media`, and `ComicBook < Media`, `Media.find(:all)` will return some things that are `Record`s and some that are `ComicBook`s.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean, how do you aggregate them all, since you are actually returning an array of Model objects, I recommend this:

```
Model.find(:all).collect(&:model_name)
```

This should give you an array of model names of the classes that you have returned from the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling "Model", don't you already know the class?

If you call

```
Post.find(:all)
```

the returned records will be of class **Post**.

Comment: This is not always true. If you are dealing with an STI model, and you are querying the parent/base model, it can return subclasses of this that are known as different model names.